# How to use bibtex with subfile

Tags: bibtex, subfiles

I am a newbie, and I have been looking for the solution for a while. But if I use subfile for separate files, how can I do citations in the subfiles that refer to the global bibliography? Like if I insert a bibliography in the main tex file, that will include every citation I have in every subfiles?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome! Before I commented, someone downvoted your question, probably because it lacked a minimal working example (MWE). But I see that you have responded to a posted answer, I upvoted. However, in the future, be sure to provide code in response to code, not just ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Citations in subfiles that refer to a global bibliography that is set up in the main file work exactly as if there was no subfile.

The following is the file `main.tex` which does not contain any `\cite` commands, but prints the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1.tex}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The following is the file `chapter1.tex` which contains the only `\cite` command.

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\cite{key}
\end{document}
```

To get the desired result, you can compile `main.tex` using PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX.

---

Alternative approach using `\include` instead of the `subfiles` package:

The following is a MWE that uses `\include{filename}` commands instead of the `subfiles` package:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
some test
\ref{chapter}

\include{chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

`chapter1.tex`:

```
\chapter{title}
\label{chapter}
some text
\cite{key}
```

Using this approach, TeXMaker auto completes `\cite` and `\ref` commands in both files equally.

Please note the differences in the chapter files in comparison to the `subfiles` approach.
And please also keep in mind that `\include{filename}` does a `\clearpage` before and after `\include{filename}`.

Further information: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/134144)

Comment: Thanks. When I use Texmaker, and type \cite command, the list of sources do not populate automatically. If I write in the main file then there is no issues. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @bilibili: On my system the auto completion of citation keys generally works fine on main and sub files. There may though be problems with the MWE in my answer as it uses filecontents. If you create a MWE with a separate `.bib` file (and maybe press `Edit` --> `Refresh Bibliography` in TexMaker) the auto completion should work on both files.

Comment: thank you very much. How about the ref command for labels? They normally do not populate. So what i did is to do this in the main tex file:
\include{main.tex}
\include{abstract.tex}
\include{intro.tex}
\begin{document}

This way I can use \ref that include all the labels in the structure. Is this a legit way?

Comment: @bilibili `\include` before `\begin{document}` appears strange to me. I have edited my answer to include a MWE that demonstrates the usage of `\include`.  I would prefer this solution, as with the `subfiles` example TeXMaker does not auto complete `\ref` commands to labels in sub files.

Comment: This approach does not allow compiling `chapter1.tex` with citations included, right? How to do that?  The whole point of `subfiles` is to allow subcompilation, I believe.